# sql not a valid month error in sql command line

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlcommand

Actually I was trying to get all columns within a date range in Oracle db and I am successful in doing so in SQL Developer but when I execute the same code in SQL command line interface I get an error

> ORA-01843 : not a valid month

I know its an error which comes in to_date format but it gets executed in SQL developer as exactly I expected but not in SQL command line. Why does this happen??

```
select to_date('01/04/2020') from dual;
```

Even this command is not working.

I had tried all format methods for the `to_date` method conversion and I checked `nls_date_format` which shows `'DD-MM-RR'`

Comment: thanks i didnt put a command to alter the session, but my problem was the query which i build was working as exactly as i wanted in sql developer but it was not working in sql command line, so when i added a query to alter the session in sql command line it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to always provide appropriate format mask. Don't rely on Oracle implicitly converting & guessing what you wanted to do.

String that looks like `'01/04/20'` could be *anything*, depending on format you used (`dd/mm/yy`, `yy/dd/mm`, `mm/yy/dd` ... all of that is valid, but only one is correct).

```
SQL> alter session set nls_Date_format = 'dd-mm-rr';

Session altered.

SQL> select to_date('01/04/2020', 'dd/mm/yyyy') result from dual;

RESULT
------------------------------
01-04-20

SQL>
```